# two errors displayed if i sort one the other pops up TypeError: cart is not a constructor in post method and cart.find is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, mean

**TypeError: cart is not a constructor** have been working with these tech for over year and never faced  such issues so please do help

```
  router.post('/add-to-cart', isLoggedIn, function (req, res, next) {

    cart = new cart({
        price: req.body.price,
        adult: req.body.adult,
        children: req.body.children,
        kids: req.body.kids,
        arrival: req.body.arrival,
        departure: req.body.depart,
        totalprice: req.body.subtotal,
        user_id: req.body.userid,
        id: req.body.productId,
    });
    console.log("cart1592: " + cart);
    cart.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error', 'Error: ' + err.message);
            console.log("cart1596: " + cart);
            return res.redirect('/');
        }
        // res.flash('thanks for your feedback');
        console.log("cart1600: " + cart);
        return res.redirect('/shopping-cart');


});
});
```

**imported it here**

```
var router = express.Router();
var cart = require('../models/cart');
var review = require('../models/reviews');
```

**cart.find is not a function** have been working with these tech for over year and never faced  such issues so please do help

```
 router.get('/shopping-cart', isLoggedIn, function (req, res, next) {
    var slug3 = req.params.slug3;
    qryFilter = { "_id": req.user._id };


    var user = req.user._id;
    console.log(user);
    cart.find(function (err, cart) {
            console.log(cart);
            event = new Event({
                namespace: 'products',
                person: {
                    id: req.user._id,
                    first_name: req.user.first_name,
                    last_name: req.user.last_name,
                    email: req.user.email,
                },
                action: 'view',
                thing: {
                    type: "product",
                    id: product._id,
                    name: product.name,
                    category: product.category,
                    Product_Group: product.Product_Group
                }
            });
            event.save(function (err, eventId) {
                if (err) {
                    return -1;
                }

                res.send(cart);

        });
    });
});
```

**this is my schema** have been working with these tech for over year and never faced  such issues so please do help

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var schema = new Schema({
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: false
    },
    adult: {
        type: Number,
        required: false
    },

    children: {
        type: Number,
        required: false
    },
    id: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    kids: {
        type: Number,
        required: false
    },
    arrival: {
        type: Date,
        required: false
    },
    user_id: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    departure: {
        type: Date,
        required: false
    },
    totalprice: {
        type: Number,
        required: false
    },

});
module.exports = mongoose.model('cart',schema);
```

Comment: Where is the cart object definition?

Comment: you just meant to import it from schema on the top right? i have included the section containing it above in this edit please help if i am doing it in a wrong way

Comment: Show me the models/cart content

Comment: thanks for the response have figured it out and yeah model is attached

Answer (score 0):

error solved The reason is because on declaring var cart that overwrites the other declaration i had for cart so it displayed cart is not constructor.so it was either this or that one of them only worked and one condition failed each time thanks for the response